# 2D List having unequal row/column lengths specified from list

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
num_row = 3
num_col = [2, 4, 8]

# columns, row
list_2d = [[0 for i in range(num_row)] for j in num_col]
#list_2d = [[0 for i in range(num_row)] for j in num_col[:]] # SyntaxError: invalid syntax
#list_2d = [[0 for i in range(num_row)] for num_col[:]] #SyntaxError: invalid syntax
#list_2d = [[0 for i in range(num_row)] for j in num_col[j]] #IndexError: list index out of range


print('\nlist_2d:')
for i in list_2d:
    print(i)

print('\nnum_col:')
for j in num_col[:]:
    print(j)
```

My goal is to declare/initialize a list of list where the number of row elements is provided by an array (i.e., the first element of the array gives the number of columns in the first row, the second element of the array gives the number of columns in the second row, etc.). For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to accomplish this.

What I get:

```
list_2d:
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0]


num_col:
2
4
8
```

What I want:

```
[0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[0 for i in range(j)] for j in num_col]
```

`num_row` will always be three, you want to use `j` instead

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use `*`. Here's an example

```
>>> [0]*10
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Applying the same, you could also do this as follows:

```
num_col = [2,4,8]
result = [[0]*j for j in num_col]
```